# Underscore.js's map function is mutating the array of DOM elements in-place and returning 'undefined' WHY?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming

I'm trying to use the `map` function over an array of options, do some typical operations with them, and then return the new array of options. `map` should create a new array of objects and not mutate the old list of objects at all. However, Underscore.js is doing the exact opposite! It's mutating the DOM elements in place and returning undefined. I also tried it with Lazy.js. At first it works as expected, but when I use the toArray() function, the elements are magically mutated.

## I have created a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/twr0Lnhr/

Please check out the fiddle to see fully what I am talking about here. But here is the function I wrote:

```
function getSelectedIndex1(options, value) {
    var newOptions = _.map(options, function(opt){
        opt.selected = opt.text == value ? 
            (function(e) {
                opt.text += ' (this is the default)';
                return true;
            }()) : 
            (function() {
                opt.style.color = 'red';
                return false;
            }());
        return opt;
    });
    return newOptions;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Am I doing something wrong or do the libraries not work like that?

Comment: You are mutating the option objects...

Comment: my understanding is that, in the background of the map function, it first makes a copy of the object in the array and then passes that copied object to the callback function, and the return of that callback function is inserted into the new array. At leas that's the way it SHOULD work....

Comment: the real [].map() makes a copy, but _.map() cheats and uses the orig to run faster. it also doesn't skip empty slots in sparse arrays like [].map does...

Comment: @dandavis, who told you that? native `[].map()` doesn't clone array items either.

Comment: @meandre: you're right, [].map() doesn't clone array items, it clones the array itself. well to be specific, it gives you a new array of the same size as before... this is why you can modify the 3rd argument "mid-stream" in _.map() to affect the original in ways you can't in [].map(); eg. using splice, pop, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` doesn't pass a copy of it's items to the mapping function, it passes the same items.

Just do: `opt = opt.cloneNode()` as the first line in your mapping function.

Comment: good solution. yup, funny how I came to the same conclusion when explaining myself in the other comment. And Lazy.js doesn't mutate the elements until calling toArray() because of the way that it forces lazy evaluation, interesting...